# Material Design Animation transition between RecyclerView and Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, material-components-android, android-transitions

I am trying to create animation transition from my RecyclerView item click to an activity like in the picture below:

What is the best way to do this?
[image: Material Design Animation transition between RecyclerView and Activity]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition

Comment: I apologize for answering so long. Thanks for the answer. Useful information

Comment: I'm glad that helped!